# When was AUC first attested?

Tags: ancient-rome, date

Ancient Romans generally identified years by the names of their consuls. When was AUC, *ab urbe condita*, or any of its various abbreviations first used? It was very popular in the Renaissance but it may have been used in classical times (though I do not know of any cases).

Comment: Did you look at the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_urbe_condita) page?

Comment: @user2448131 Yes, but I didn't actually see any citations of its use. Many references to the age of the city, but none to attested use of AUC/ab urbe condita/etc.

Comment: It seems attributed to Varro, but no work given.  A lot of Varro works are lost...